# Proper Way to Return/Filter Values from AJAX'd PHP Script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, types

Consider the following:

```
<?php
//daytime_check.php
    $is_daytime = false;
    if ($is_daytime) {
        echo '1';
    } else {
        echo '0';
    }
?>
```

==================================================================================

```
// javascript/jQuery
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'daytime_check.php',
    success: function(response) {
        if(response == false) {
            alert('Goodnight, brother');
        } else {
            alert('Day\'s a wastin, brother');
        }            
    },
    error: function() {
        //handle error
    }
});
```

This is how I have heretofore handled the responses from my AJAX'd PHP scripts. I'm hoping someone out there can give me some hints on a better way, as this current method feels pretty clunky.

Especially clunky is handling the "filtering" of the PHP script's output on the JS side. For example:

In this case, the response from PHP is going to be a JS var `response ='0'`. Now one can't simply use `if (!response)...` in JS to filter, because apparently `!response` evaluates to `false`, while, interestingly, `response == false` evaluates to `true`. Something to do with type juggling, I suppose.

Since the only way I can return things from PHP is in text (`echo` statements), I can't return proper true/false values to filter on when I get to the JS side. Is there a better way to handle this?

I hope this made at least a little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stil return any type you would like to. Just use JSON response.

```
// you can return what ever you want via JSON
die(json_encode(array(
    'isDateTime' => $is_datetime,
    'message'    => 'Some optional message to display',
    'timestamp'  => time()
)));
```

This will output this string:

```
{"isDateTime":false,"message":"Some optional message to display","timestamp":1332792739}
```

And on client side jQuery will parse this response:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'daytime_check.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        if (response.isDateTime) { ... }
        // typeof response.isDateTime == 'boolean'
        // alert(response.message)         
    },
    error: function() {
        //handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: I like this. Also interesting is how you use `die()` when returning a value from PHP. Is that just to kill the script for memory concerns?

Comment: Well you can use `echo` or `print`, whatever. I prefer `die` because this way I can be sure that I output only JSON and after that script will shut down.

Comment: I like that idea. I haven't seen it done before. Seems to make good sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have to display the message in success handler then why don't you return the message itself?

```
<?php
//daytime_check.php
    $is_daytime = false;
    if ($is_daytime) {
        echo "Day's a wastin', brother";
    } else {
        echo "Goodnight, brother";
    }
?>

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'daytime_check.php',
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);         
    },
    error: function() {
        //handle error
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, this is oversimplified code for example/brevity purposes. In this case, what you suggested would be fine. But I'm looking for something to handle all cases.

Comment: returning `1` or `0` is fine. You can just check of `if(response)` which will pass through any non zero or non null or non empty value.

Comment: Can you clarify? Pretty sure checking `if (response)` will work when `response` in fact points to a string representation of `true/false` as `"0"` or `"1"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a neat solution provided by an intelligent former co-worker.

Return values from your PHP scripts in the following manner:

```
<?php
    // To return an error
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => '[error message here]',
        )
    );
    // To return a successful response
    echo json_encode(
        array(
            'success' => true,
            'response' => [return value here],
        )
    );
```

This way, we can easily do logic on the JS side:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'ajax_example.php',
    success: function(response) {
                 response = JSON.parse(response);
                 if (!response.success) {
                     alert(response.message);
                 } else {
                     console.log(response.response);    
                 }
    },
    error: function() {
               //handle error
               alert('error doing ajax, mate');
           }
    });
```